Artifact okio 3.2.0 not found in docker image using maven and okhttp 4.11.0
Why is transitive dependency okio 3.2.0 missing in the docker image, but not in the rpm we're building? Both have okio-jvm 3.2.0 but the docker image won't run because it says ArtifactNotFoundException: Artifact okio not found.
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>4.11.0</version>
</dependency>

